# XML Declaration contains newline character instead of double quote - when creating xml document in C#

Tags: c#, xmldocument, xml-declaration

I am creating an xml document in c# used the following code to create

xml declaration at top of the file

```
  XmlNode docNode = xmlDoc.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0", "UTF-8", null);
                    xmlDoc.AppendChild(docNode);
```

and I am getting the xml declaration as follows:

```
<?xml version=\1.0\  encoding=\ utf-8\ ?>
```

What i need is `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`

Tried string manipulation to remove the **'\'** character with double quote but the value is not changing, what changes should i make?
This is the whole code for creating the remaining nodes and all

```
  XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();

            XmlNode docNode = xmlDoc.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0", "UTF-8", null);
            xmlDoc.AppendChild(docNode);


            XmlNode rootNode = xmlDoc.CreateElement("urlset");
            XmlAttribute attribute = xmlDoc.CreateAttribute("xmlns");
            attribute.Value = "www.test.com";
            rootNode.Attributes.Append(attribute);
            xmlDoc.AppendChild(rootNode);
            xmlDoc.Save("test-doc.xml");
```

Comment: Please provide [MCVE] that shows how do you get that result. It is *very* unlikely code in the post actually creates broken XML. Side note if you are looking at values in debugger that's totally different story but that's not what post says.

Comment: Code in the question produces exactly what post claims is expected (as expected): `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<urlset xmlns="www.test.com" />`. It is still unclear what exactly you have problem with.